# Is it possible to remap the enter key on a iPad Smart Keyboard?

Tags: ipad, smart-keyboard

I have an iPad Pro 12.9“, third generation, with an Apple Smart Keyboard.

I‘d like to remap the keys so that the enter key and right shift key are switched, i.e. to enter a new line, I hit right shift and to capitalize Letters, I use Enter.

I know that special keys like caps lock, control, option or command can be remapped, but didn‘t find any way to remap other keys.

Can it be done? Is there perhaps an app that can do it?

Comment: You might be out of luck if Apple doesn’t provide this as overriding return is explicitly called out as a rejection item in keyboard extensions - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions

Comment: Thanks @bmike for confirming my suspicion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** it can't be done.

Apple doesn’t provide this functionality, and  overriding the return key is explicitly called out as a rejection item in keyboard extensions.

See also [App Store Review Guidelines, section 4.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions):

[image: Screenshot from App Store Review Guidelines with part about repurposing return key highlighted]

Thanks [@bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) for the info!